# Django oauth toolkit using implicit grant type

Tags: python, django, angularjs, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to authorize my users from an angularjs frontend app against a python/django backend using oauth toolkit. Using implicit "grant type" I always receive a redirection with parameter "?error=unauthorized_client" though the username and password were correct. I tried grant type "authorization code" without any trouble. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [OAuth2 spec](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-12.html), in the implicit grant section (4.2.2.1):

> unauthorized_client
>
> > The client is not authorized to request an access token using this method.

My understanding is that the authorization server doesn't allow implicit grants.

Comment: I pretty sure that my server allows implicit grants but after reading your cite from OAuth2 Spec I think that the way I tried to get the token is not valid for implicit grants

Answer (score 2):

The Authorization Server created with Oauth toolkit allows grant_type=implicit.
Here is an example of how to call the Server asking for the token,using a HTML form.

```
<form id="user_form" method="get" action="Your Oauth Authorize URL" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">

Client_id: <input type="text" name="client_id" value="" size="100" />
<br />

Redirect Ui:<input type="text" name="redirect_uri" value="Your redirect_uri">
<br />

<input type="hidden" name="response_type" value="token">
{% csrf_token %}

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Regarding the registration of your app, just be sure that you define your application as :

- Client type: Public
- Authorization grant type: Implicit
- Redirect Uri: Your redirect uri

After submitting the form you will be redirected to your Oauth Authorization site and you will be asked for permission.

As soon as you accept, you will be redirected to your redirect url and you will have the token at the fragment of the Uri:

http://**YourRedirectUri**/#expires_in=**EXPIRATIONTIME**&state=&token_type=**TYPE**&scope=**TYPE**&access_token=**VALUEOFTHETOKEN**